# How can I prevent certain roles from editing other roles?

Tags: 7, users

I have user roles User Role 1, 2, and 3. I want a simple module that will make User Role 1 only be able to edit and administer users in User Role 2, and not User Role 3. Does anybody know of any module or other easy method to do that? It seems like there *must* have been somebody else who did something about their moderators being able to delete their admin accounts?

Please note that I'm not asking for anything about restricting the **permission** changing ability of roles.

Comment: Would a simple redirect on the user edit form work? Or would you want User Role 3 to not even appear in to User Role 1 when they navigate to admin/people ?

Comment: The problem with redirects is that they can just stop the page from refreshing by pressing the X button. I don't think redirects is the way to go. @visibility: they should be able to *see* the users, just not, for instance, delete them, or reset the password, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [userprotect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) module can handle that.

Comment: Yes! Yes! This is exactly what I've been looking for! This will save me hours of time and trouble. I never found it -- it doesn't appear on any google searches I tried or any related module blocks at drupal.org. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[Administer Users by Role](http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) does that (and is now ported to Drupal 7).